# HTML/PHP: How can we insert PHP variable into anchor tag of html?

Tags: php, html

I have a .php page which has a lot of HTML parts in it.
I am running a FOR loop and for each value in FOR loop, I want to pass a PHP variable in anchor tag which is inside the loop.

I have tried this:

```
for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{ 
<a href = "Test.html?ID= <?php $i ?> > Sample text </a>
}
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: what's with the syntax? Is this JS or PHP? if it's PHP, missing echo

Comment: then you're not using "echo". simply injecting pure HTML into PHP and missing a quote.

Comment: yup found it! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number of ways.  The point is to not mix the HTML with the PHP, keep them separately parse-able.  Something like this:

```
for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{ 
    echo '<a href="Test.html?ID=' . $i . '"> Sample text </a>';
}
```

(In this example all of the code is PHP, and the HTML is a string that's `echo`-ed to the output.)

Or this:

```
for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{
?>
    <a href="Test.html?ID=<?php echo $i; ?>"> Sample text </a>
<?php
}
```

(In this example the PHP code is wrapped in `<?php ?>` tags and the HTML is kept outside those tags.)

As long as you keep PHP code in the `<?php ?>` tags and HTML out of those tags, the parsers will know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong and you are not outputting anything, replace it with:

```
for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{ 
  echo '<a href="Test.html?ID='.$i.'>Sample text</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The html has to be included in `echo` while using in php

```
 <?php
    for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
    { 
       echo '<a href="Test.html?ID='.$i.'>Sample text</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{ 
      <a href = "Test.html?ID= <?php $i ?> > Sample text </a>
}
```

If above lines are code u have tried, its not in proper format!
u running loop in php! so u cannot put html tags directly in php file!
use echo to display html tags!

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
       echo "<a href=test.html?id=$i>Click here</a>";

}
```

Hope it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo "<a href=\"Test.html?id='.$i.'\">Click here</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i =0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{
?>
<a href="Test.html?ID=<?php echo $i; ?>"> Sample text </a>
<?php
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It's work for me

<?php 
  if($row['status'] == 0){ ?>
  <?php   echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' Onclick='return ConfirmDelete();' href='requestManage.php?reject=<?php echo {$row['id']}; ?>' role='button'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>";?>
  <?php    }else{ ?>
  <?php 
 echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' style=' pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;' Onclick='return ConfirmDelete();' href='requestManage.php?reject=<?php echo {$row['id']}; ?>' role='button'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>";
         ?>
 <?php  } ?>
```